# How to solve this quadratic equation with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The equation $$7x^2+2kx+k^2=k+7$$ where $k$ is a constant has two distinct real roots. Show that $k$ satisfies the inequality $$6k^2- 7k - 49 < 0.$$
>   find the range of possible values of K

Comment: Why do you need to complete the square? What have you tried? What is the [discriminant](http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/spoken/here/2class/320/quadequ.htm) of the equation?

Answer (score 2):

Since $7x^2+2kx+k^2-k-7$ is a quadratic in $x$ with discriminant$$(2k)^2-28(k^2-k-7)=-4(6k^2-7k-49),$$it has two distinct real roots iff this expression is positive.

Comment: Where has the negative 4 come from and this isn't a solution

Comment: @JøHñ Of course - this is the first part (the proof: "Show that $k$ satisfies..."). Now, to find the range of $k$'s you need to solve the inequality $6k^2-7k-49<0$.

Comment: @JøHñ Not a solution? I hope my edit addresses that.